# How do I embed application manifest in F# application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, f#, c#-to-f#

How can I embed [application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191.aspx) with my F# application?
With C# projects it can be specified in projects properties but I haven't found any similar in F# project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With VS 2015 and F# 4 (I haven't tested earlier versions, but it probably also works in them) both the compiler and the MSBuild files directly support embedding a manifest in an exe, the option is just not surfaced on the GUI.

You can just add the manifest as a normal file and add the following to your project file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This adds the following parameter to the call to the compiler: `--win32manifest:app.manifest`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easyest way is using mt.exe tool (Section 2 in this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cheller/archive/2006/08/24/how-to-embed-a-manifest-in-an-assembly-let-me-count-the-ways.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up modifying my `fsproj`-file to contain the following at the end:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\mt.exe&quot; -manifest App.manifest -outputresource:&quot;$(TargetPath)&quot;"
          Condition="('$(OutputType)' == 'Exe' Or '$(OutputType)' == 'WinExe') And Exists('App.manifest')" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: @RubenBartelink Petr's answer suggests using `mt.exe` in post-build command as opposed to mine adding additional task to the `AfterBuild` target.

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying that a) if you ask a question and b) someone answers it mentioning the tool you are suggesting with the canonical article and c) you simply wire it in differently then it would be fair for you to i) upvote him ii) acknowledge that it was a useful answer. Also, a postbuild step only fires if the DLL/EXE is rebuilt whereas AfterBuild runs unconditionally (there are various approaches depending the degree of MSBuild-fu you want to get into - this stuff matters a lot in bigger builds)

Comment: Having said all that, in retrospect the fact that you have an actual working snippet has value so downvoting is a bit strong (I've done the same in terms of self-answering even when other answers helped a lot but like to think I acknowledge a bit)